# Remove DataObject default sort

Tags: php, orm, silverstripe

I have a `DataObject` with a default sort:

```
class Author extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array('Name' => 'Varchar');
    private static $default_sort = 'Name ASC';
}
```

I want to `Author::get()` the data but with no sort.

so given...

```
Author::create(array('Name' => 'DEF'))->write();
Author::create(array('Name' => 'ABC'))->write();
```

This would output *ABC* then *DEF* using the sort, but if the sort was cleared I'd expect *DEF* then *ABC*.

I've tried `Author::get()->sort('')` and `Author::get()->sort(null)` but both return *ABC* then *DEF* again.

Note The reason I'm asking is that I have a complex query (using joins) where this is causing an issue and I'm getting an error with it if I try and set the sort too.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY "_SortColumn0" ASC' at line 1

So the solution, and what I'd like to know anyway, is how to clear the default sort for the specific `Author::get()` while keeping the existing default sort on the `DataObject`?

Comment: `private static $default_sort = 'Name DESC';`

Comment: Thank you @Anant but no, I want to keep the default sort for all other cases.

Comment: Have you tried `->sort(null)`? I haven't tested this.

Comment: @3dgoo I had, sorry, didn't add that to the question the sort function just returns if you don't pass it something to sort with.

Comment: If you want the order the items have been created, why not sort by ID or Created ?

Comment: @wmk I state in the question that I'm after *no* sort being applied, it looks the same as "sort by XYZ" but it isn't it is *no sort* which is why I've accepted Dans answer as it removes the default sort

Comment: BTW, I agree that setting `->sort(null)` should really unset the sort - would you like to open an issue (or even PR) on GitHub for this?

Comment: @DanHensby done.. https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/5897

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the only way to unset the sort would be to manipulate the `DataQuery` that underpins the `DataList` which is returned when running `Author::get()`.

```
$dq = Author::get()->dataQuery();
$dq->sort(null, null, true);
$authors = Author::get()->setDataQuery($dq);
```